# MySQL Database Export (100 Rows from each table in a database)

Tags: mysql, database, export

I'm looking for a way to export +/- 100 rows from each table in a database into a MySQL script.

The reason for this is I have setup a mock Web server on my laptop, and want to replicate the structure and some data from our server. The databases on the server have been poorly setup with no indexes at all.

Once I have exported the +/- 100 Rows I want to recreate a mock environment on my laptop so I can work on improving this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: This can be done with a one-liner, using --where="true limit 100". See https://serverfault.com/questions/173834/mysql-dump-of-talble-limit-100

Answer (score 4):

### Export

Please try the following for **exporting** within the machine you are logged in

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt --lock-tables=false --where="1 limit 1000" database_name > db_backup.sql
```

**Exporting** from SSH try below

```
mysqldump -h SERVER_IP -u root -p --opt --lock-tables=false --where="1 limit 1000" database_name > db_ssh_backup.sql
```

### Import

Please try the following for **importing** within the machine you are logged in

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt --lock-tables=false --where="1 limit 1000" database_name < db_backup.sql
```

**Importing** via SSH try below

```
mysqldump -h SERVER_IP -u root -p --opt --lock-tables=false --where="1 limit 1000" database_name < db_ssh_backup.sql
```

### Note

**Export / Import from server** may throw Unknown table 'COLUMN_STATISTICS' in information_schema (1109) error

Use the below flag to solve this issue

```
--column-statistics=0
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump -u {username} -p {db_name} --where="true limit 100" > db_name.sql

Answer (score -2):

I doubt there are any tools available to export each table of 100 rows of a whole database at one time.

However you can export 100 rows of each table one by one:

goto http://topnew.net/sidu to download that little tool.

And export your table in the following way:

```
1 - click on your table name
2 - click export
3 - in where section, input: 1=1 limit 100
```

It will export max 100 rows for that table

And you need export tables one by one